# intent.getAction() is always null inside onNewIntent() when NFC tag scan

Tags: java, android, nfc

I tagged nfc after running the app I made.

After the tag, newIntent is executed, but getAction() always return null.

I have attached java code and xml code.

Please.

Please tell me the solution.

bellow code is java code

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView nfcText;
    private final String[][] techList = new String[][] {
            new String[] {NfcA.class.getName(), NfcB.class.getName(),
                    NfcF.class.getName(), NfcV.class.getName(),
                    NdefFormatable.class.getName(), TagTechnology.class.getName(),
                    IsoDep.class.getName(), MifareClassic.class.getName(),
                    MifareUltralight.class.getName(), Ndef.class.getName()}
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this,
                getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        //filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);

        filter.addAction(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
        filter.addAction(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
        filter.addAction(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED);
        NfcAdapter nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, new IntentFilter[]{filter}, this.techList);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        //super.onNewIntent(intent);
        //setIntent(intent);
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction()) ||
                NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction()) ||
                NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            nfcText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nfcText);
            nfcText.setText(byteArrayToHexString(intent.getByteArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_ID)));
        }
    }
}
```

The picture below is the param value when checking intent.getAction().

[image]

and bellow code is androidManifest.xml code

androidManifest

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.nfcactivity">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10"></uses-sdk>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.NfcActivity">
        <activity >
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you managed to solve it?